# The named parameter 'onTap' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I currently learning Flutter and I'm very new to it. in my app I used responsive grid package and add Text in responsive container. i wanted to go to another page when tap on this text but my bad it gives me this error.

```
The named parameter 'onTap' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onTap'.
```

i used following code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      child: ResponsiveGridRow(children: [
        ResponsiveGridCol(
          lg: 12,
          child: Container(
            height: 400,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Welcome To",
                     style: TextStyle(
                       fontSize: 40,
                       color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("our App",
                     style: TextStyle(
                       fontSize: 40,
                       color: Colors.white,
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
              ],
              ),
          ),
        ),
             ResponsiveGridCol(
          xs: 4,
          md: 2,
          child: Container(
              height: 18,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text("Login",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13,
                      // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      color: Colors.orange[800])),
              onTap: () { // i got error here
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()),
                );
              }
              ),
        )
      ]),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widget does not have an `onTap` property you need to create as show below by wrapping the widget that you need to be clickable with a `gesture detector` or InkWell

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () { 
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()),
                );
              }
     child:Container(
              height: 18,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text("Login",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 13,
                      // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      color: Colors.orange[800])),
              
              )),
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Container` widget does not have onTap property try to wrap it in `InkWell` like this:

```dart
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()),
        );
      },
   child: Container(
      height: 18,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Text("Login",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 13,
              // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              color: Colors.orange[800])),
    )))
```